# UiTableViewCell not showing in full width as Table Width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

my problem is explain in image below
[image]

the UITableViewCell Position is not fit in tableview.It have space at start and end and don't know why.

actually i'm not able to resolve this issue and also not able to get solution on web(or i might be searching differently)

Please help to resolve this.

Editing:
Adding Constrains screenshot
[image]

this screenshot is for last cell in table which have UILabel,UIView and in side View UITextField.

Comment: Have you check constraints?

Comment: @Neon Samuel..I added the EqualWidth constrains to TextField. and yes there are no constraints error..!  should I show constraints ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AutoLayout, be sure to set the proper value depending on the fact that you have margin activated or not. You can also check the Views tree in the Storyboard in order to see where your problem might be located.

Comment: No there is no margin to start or end.

Comment: did you put first name in a row , then last name in a row, then position in a row.. etc?? Did you use storyboard? Did you use autolayout? Did you use the Any:any settings in Autolayout? is your screenshot a screenshot of the actual app running or is it a storyboard screenshot?

Comment: Yes i'm using storyboard and Autolayout but not Any:any setting and Yes it is screenshot of actual app not storyboard...! I when I add only Label and textfield without autolayout constrains then work but as expected means in small view in iphone 6 but when add autolayout constrains then wired like in screenshot.

Comment: ok, I guess the best is if you can show your Autolayout settings for each items in your "Position" Cell

Comment: Thx, however the constraints you show are not all visible on the screenshot. Also, the problem you have is with the cell containing 3 TextViews if I'm correct.

Comment: Hi @Mikael Thank you so much for help..actually I added the 3 textfields in UIView that cause this problem when I remove UIView and add directly in Cell the issue gone...Strange..!. any ways actually you are  asking question thats why i tried from some other ways.

Comment: good :) maybe you can add your own answer to this question then.